# CPU usage increases for Empty Infinite While loop

Tags: c#, performance, while-loop

Can anyone explain me why the following Infinite loop takes a lot of CPU usage (`CPU usage has increased upto 50% if total core is 2 and 100% if total CPU core is just 1`)

But if I un-comment the line it reduces to 1 or 2 CPU usage?

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("hello..");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because it keeps evaluating loop as fast as it possibly can.

Comment: I think downvotes on this question are unfair. Just because it is obvious to experienced engineers does not mean it is obvious to all. There are subtle issues of blocking I/O here that the question brings up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because your CPU cannot do anything else while it's executing that loop. The CPU is not aware that the infinite loop isn't a complicated calculation that just requires a lot of iterations. Hence it keeps on evaluating that true condition infintely resulting in consumption of increase CPU usage.

You may also like to check [Halt and Catch Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire)

**On a side note:**

If you want to avoid the infinity loop then you can simply use a `WaitHandle`. To let the process be exited from the outer world use a `EventWaitHandle` with a unique string.

Answer (score 7):

`Console.WriteLine` is a blocking (interruptable) I/O call, so other things can happen while the processor is blocked on I/O.  In fact, it spends *significantly more* time blocked on I/O than it does evaluating the trivial condition `true` and jumping!

Without the writeline call, your processor is completely busy and cannot be interrupted.

Try replacing `Console.WriteLine` with something like `int x = 1`, or anything that does not block.  This should behave like the empty body case.

Comment: Good answer. I like your `int x = 1` experiment. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The CPU spends all its time checking that `true` is true, and the compiler didn't optimize it away. With the `WriteLine`, the process can block when writing to the console, which reduces overall CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

When the line is commented out the while loop does nothing and just consumes CPU spinning in a circle. When you call WriteLine your program makes a call to the operating system which suspends your process temporarily. This leads to your program being "blocked" for most of the time and consuming CPU only between write() system calls.