# How do I continously check if a statement is true

Tags: python, alarm

I wrote this short program to make an alarm. Basically you choose a time to set the alarm and it will play analog-watch-alarm_daniel-simion.wav.
I have tried using a while True: statement but that didn't seem to work. Can someone please help?

```
import time
import datetime
import winsound
from datetime import datetime
lcltime =datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
print(lcltime)
while True:
    if lcltime == "22:33":
        winsound.PlaySound("analog-watch-alarm_daniel-simion.wav",  winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        break
```

Comment: Well. Supposing that `lcltime` is something other than `"22:33"` the first time around. If you want it to ever happen that `lcltime` is equal to `"22:33"` later, then `lcltime` has to *change*, yes? Can you think of a way to make that happen? For example, right before each time you check the value?

Comment: You may want to [sleep](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_sleep.htm) for a second in between checks to keep the while loop from [hogging considerable CPU time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051121/cpu-usage-increases-for-empty-infinite-while-loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put this line `lcltime=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')` inside the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just get your time variable inside your loop in order to update the timer.

```
import winsound 
from datetime import datetime
while True:
    lcltime =datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    if lcltime == "22:51":
        winsound.PlaySound("analog-watch-alarm_daniel-simion.wav",  winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        break
```

Comment: Why import `datetime` twice? You import the full `datetime` library and then import only the `datetime` class from the same library

Comment: It's given in the MWE of the OP. Also you don't need to import time. Corrected!